# How can I use right the for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have such a task. I want to create 15 divs and I want to take the background colors of these divs from the array. But here only divs are created according to 5 colors, the color of the others is undefined. How can I cycle the colors?

```js
let color = ["yellow", "green", "red", "blue", "orange"];

for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    document.write("<div style='background:" + color[i] + "'></div> ");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as it is, use modulo arithmetic.

Instead of `color[i]`, use `color[i % color.length]`, and it will work as you want.

Taking the remainder from the division of the current index by the length of the array will bind it to the range **[0;length)**, which can allow you to repeat all array indices infinitely many times. See for yourself:

| i | i % 5 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 4 |
| 15 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
let color = ["yellow", "green", "red", "blue", "orange"];


for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    document.write("<div style='background:" + color[i % (color.length)] + "'></div> ");
}
```